# Can we pass the class object inside its own method?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a class A object method which uses another class B object's method, which the argument is class A object.

```
class A(): 
    def calculate(self):
         B = B.calculator(A)
       
class B():
    def calculator(self, A):
         ...do something with A.attributes
```

It is possible to just pass attributes into the object, but I would see this possibility as the last priority. I am definitely a bit oversimplify my case, but I am wondering if there is a way to pass the entire class

Edit:
Sorry for the confusion. At the end I am trying to call class A object and A.calculate(), which will call class B obj and calculator function.

```
class A(): 
    def __init__(self, value):
         self.value = value
         
    def calculate(self):
         Bobj = B()
         Bobj.calculator(A)
       
class B():
    def calculator(self, A):
         ...do something with A.value

def main():
     Aobj = A(value)
     Aobj.calculate()
```

Comment: Why are you calling an instance method of another class when you don't have an instance? That looks very strange. Either that method should not be an instance method, or you perhaps want to inherit from `B`? It's unclear without more information

Comment: what are you trying to achieve in the end? this looks a blt like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Instead of pass `A` pass `self` to `B.calculator(self)`

Answer (score 0):

Your scenario does not currently indicate that you want to use any information from B when calculating A. There are a few ways of getting the functionality that you want.

**Scenario: B stores no information and performs calculation. B should be a function**

````
def B(value):
    ```do something with value```
    return

class A(): 
    def __init__(self, value):
         self.value = value
         
    def calculate(self):
         return B(self.value)

def main():
     Aobj = A(value)
     Aobj.calculate()
````

**Scenario: B stores some other information, but internal B information is not needed for the calculation. B should have a static method**

````
class B():
    @staticmethod
    def calculate(value):
        ```do something with value```
        return

class A(): 
    def __init__(self, value):
         self.value = value
         
    def calculate(self):
         return B.calculate(self.value)

def main():
     Aobj = A(value)
     Aobj.calculate()
````